# How to stop JFace dialog from closing after dialog.open()

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have a JFace dialog and this is how I'm opening:

```
SampleDialog dialog = new SampleDialog(shell);
if(Window.OK == dialog.open())
{
  // do something
  if(condition)
  {
    MessageBox dialog = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.OK| SWT.CANCEL);
    dialog.setText("Sample");
    dialog.setMessage("Some problem in processing");
  }
  else
  {
     // do something
  }
}
```

If the control goes to the if block , I dont want the dialog to be closed. How to achieve this?

Comment: Once `dialog.open()` was called then the dialog will opened. The control will NEVER come to the `if statement` unless user clicks on close(X), OK or Cancel button on dialog. Please update the post why you need this behaviour or what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the JFace `Dialog`s `close()` method is another way of addressing it:

```
@Override
public boolean close()
{
    if( condition )
    {
        if( this.getReturnCode() == OK )
        {
            MessageBox dialog = new MessageBox(shell, SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.OK|                   SWT.CANCEL);
            dialog.setText("Sample");
            dialog.setMessage("Some problem in processing");

            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do your check and message box display by overriding the `okPressed` method in the dialog.

```
public class SampleDialog extends Dialog
{

  @Override
  protected void okPressed()
  {
    if (condition)
     {
        // TODO show your message box
     }
    else
     {
       // Allow the dialog to close
       super.okPressed();
     } 
  }

}
```